# Curvature is global and invariant in proof of Gauss Bonnet Chern theorem

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In these notes: [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/li4.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/li4.pdf) in lemma 3.2.1 it is concluded that the two curvature forms on an overlap are equivalent. I don't understand where this comes from. In equation 16 they refer to the fact that they are producing riemannian geometry by using a principle O(n) bundle, so the curvature transforms like $\Omega_\beta = g \Omega_\alpha g^{-1}$, but this shouldn't generally cancel (meaning for $n>2$) due to noncommutation, right? But never is this restriction placed on the group, as far as I read. Am I missing something obvious about the properties about these matrices? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read carefully. It’s not the curvature forms, but the Pfaffian, which gives a global $2n$-form (not $2$-form).

Comment: True, actually that is the definition of the pfaffian of some matrix, so I feel bad about missing this. So in eq 22 they define each $\Omega_i^j$ as an entry in $\Theta$, which is the actual curvature two form, but the $\Omega_\alpha$ in eq 33 is a totally different form? I know in GBC the Pfaffian is used on the curvature, so I presume this is not just an accident of notation? Or maybe it doesn't really matter?

Comment: His notation is not what I would use. A letter other than $\Omega$ would be nice. Or write $\text{Pf}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Nice, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, @rage_man. Occasionally, it comes in handy being a Chern student :)